# Why is request.json in bottle returning None?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, bottle

I have a bottle web server and am using jQuery to do my ajax requests using json, but either one is not sending or the other is not receiving, I'm not sure which. My code is basically this:

server.py

```
@route("/jsontest", method="POST")
def jsontest():
  print(request.json)
```

Always prints None, the request is going through of course, but it doesn't appear to be receiving any data.

javascript

```
$.post("/jsontest", {username: $loginName}, login_success)
```

The javascript is trigger upon a button press and loginName is taken from an input box. In the js I've done a console.log($loginName) to ensure it's actually selecting it properly and it is, so I'm assuming the problem is in that one jQuery call or I'm not reading the data properly on the server end. Both seem pretty simple an straightforward though so I'm not sure what I may be missing.

Comment: Try `print(request.username)`

Comment: what is login_success?

Comment: Also, you're not sending json to the server, why are you looking for request.json?

Comment: login_success is a callback function, not really relevant to the code in the above example. What do you mean I'm not sending json data to the server, I thought the data portion was encoded into a json string?

Comment: request.username gives an attribute undefined error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: You are not posting JSON. You are posting regular form-encoded data.

Answer (score 6):

You can test your bottle method with $curl:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"UserName":"name","Password":"password"}' http://hostname/jsontest
```

Now you can print the request data by:
    `print request.json`

Comment: Doing this is better than using `POSTMAN`

Answer (score 1):

Bottle's `request.json` only works when the request's Content-type is `application/json`.  (Your jQuery POST is probably using Content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.)

In this case jQuery's `.ajax()` might be more appropriate than `.post()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should POST it as json:

`$.post("/jsontest", JSON.stringify({username: $loginName}), login_success)`